# Map a value with value inside a array using mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

Have a record with value in a aggregation.

```
_id:asdgrsdv
surname:cooper,
comapany:sabesto,
salary:15748
mapped:Array
0:Object
  name:'mark',
  age:'25',
  surname:'cooper'
1:Object
  name:'snow',
  age:'29',
  surname:'wyte'
```

how to map `surname` outside with `surname` in `mapped array` like this in mongodb aggregation

required output:

```
_id:asdgrsdv
  name:'mark',
  comapany:sabesto,
  salary:15748
  age:'25',
  surname:'cooper'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      data: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$mapped",
                  cond: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.surname",
                      "$surname"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$data"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "mapped": 0
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WaqFAdUlIG4)

Comment: is there a way to remove `1:Object
  name:'snow',
  age:'29',
  surname:'wyte'`  and keep only the matching value , because if i want to doa group afterwards. the data in is having two values for age and name ex :25,29 instead of 25

Comment: @hukkemaaruspetus It's already "removed" it from output. Do you need update your record in collection?

Comment: yes it would be more cleaner if it looked like this `_id:5e13642ee88247a6b4f2c0f8
surname:cooper,
name:'mark',
age:'25'
`  .TIA

Comment: @hukkemaaruspetus can you post please what are you trying to do after we filter `mapped` field?

Comment: @hukkemaaruspetus check again please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209077/discussion-between-hukkemaaru-spetus-and-valijon).